# Is it safe to delete previous versions of IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I am facing an issue of recovering free disk space in my main partition. I found these files in my Users folder. These folders named as previous versions of IntelliJ allocate 1.5GB in my disk space. Is it safe to delete these files?

[image: preview of files]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to delete these directories if you no longer use the specified IDE versions.

Note that location of the IDE directories [has changed](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) since 2020.1 release.

Answer (score 58):

Not sure when it was added, but Intellij now has a feature in the UI to delete old directories.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#clean-up-old-ide-dirs

[image]

Comment: This is great. Also removed leftovers that I did not find myself. And you get to choose what to keep.

Comment: Thank to Jetbranis for this awesome feature and you for this awesome answer.